# Update Column Using Random Unique Values from a Different Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table say Table1 with Columns Referral_ID and Company Number, I have another table Table2 with a lot of unique Address IDS and Company Number.

I need to bring a Unique Address ID randomly from table2 to table1 where company code = company code?

Can i do this with Oracle SQL?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle???

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: SELECT SALESFORCE_ID FROM
(SELECT SALESFORCE_ID FROM SF_ADDR_PLACEHOLDER WHERE COMPANY = '230'
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )   this gives me a unique ID, but how to bring this unique ID to another table and how to do it for the remaining 162 rows in my table?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Version 20.4.1.407

Comment: @NirajBahl Your Oracle database version, not your SQL Developer version. Your SQL Developer version doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm . . . You can use a lateral join if you want an *arbitrary* address rather than a *random* address:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.company_number = t1.company_number and rownum = 1
     ) t2
     on 1=1;
```

If you actually want a random address that is the same per company number, you can use:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company_number order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.company_number = t1.company_number and
        seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae85f159e399ffb4cdef2f672d2827d8) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the syntax works.

Comment: select t1.*, t2.*
from SF_ORPHANREFERRALS_V1 t1 left join lateral
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by COMPANY order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
      from SF_ADDR_PLACEHOLDER t2
     ) t2
     on t2.company = t1.nhc_companycode and
        seqnum = 1; ) t2
     on 1=1; is this correct way?

Comment: The query does not run for me. It is giving me an issue of Unknown command, probably something wrong with the brackers?

Comment: select t1.*, t2.*
    from SF_ORPHANREFERRALS_V1 t1 left join lateral
         (select t2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by COMPANY order by dbms_random.random) as seqnum
          from SF_ADDR_PLACEHOLDER t2
         ) t2
         on t2.COMPANY = t1.nhc_companycode and
            seqnum = 1;

Comment: I was able to run this query, but i found out that not all rows have a random address ID.

Comment: @NirajBahl . . . Then there are no addresses for those companies.

Comment: how do restrict from getting the same IDs again and again? As any record in my Table1 should not have a similar address ID in the future?

Comment: @NirajBahl . . . I don't actually like playing the game of "guess the question".  I think you should ask a new question, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what "random" means.  Also be clear about what to do if there are no addresses for a company and whether companies appear multiple times in the first table.

Comment: I apologise for the confusion, i will put a new question in the forum.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593619/update-a-column-in-a-table-using-randomly-picked-unique-values-from-another-table