# Update a column in a table using randomly picked unique values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Expanding [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592227/) to restrict it from updating duplicate values.

---

I have a **table1** with columns:

| refid | CompanyNumber | AddressID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 230 | null |
| yzf | 239 | null |

I have another table **table2** with columns

| address Id | company |
| --- | --- |
| 11223344 | 231 |
| 11223345 | 230 |
| 11223354 | 239 |
| 11223334 | 239 |

I would like to fetch a unique ID randomly from Table2 and update the column address ID in table1 on company number = company where Address ID is null?

Also, I will adding new rows in table1 daily, how can I restrict the duplicate address ID from getting fetched from table2?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a trigger for inserting on table1.
Then you select all AddressId's from table2 that are not already set in table1, order them randomly and just pick the first one.
A working example of such a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1 
FOR EACH ROW /* Trigger for each new row inserted into table1 */
BEGIN
SELECT addressId INTO :new.ADDRESSID /* Set AddressId for new row in table1 */ FROM 
(
   SELECT table2.addressId FROM table2
   LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.CompanyNumber = table2.company AND table1.AddressID = table2.addressId
   WHERE table1.AddressID IS NULL /* Not already in table1 */ AND table2.Company = :new.COMPANYNUMBER /* Select all addressIds matching the company number */
   ORDER BY dbms_random.value /* order them randomly */
 ) hits
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1; /*Only pick the first randomly ordered one*/
    
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN /* CompanyNumber not in table2 or no unique AddressId left */
     :new.ADDRESSID := NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table1 dst
USING (
  SELECT t1.rid,
         t2.addressID
  FROM   (
           SELECT addressId,
                  company,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY company ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
                  ) AS rn
           FROM   table2 t2
           WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM   table1 t1
             WHERE  t1.companyNumber = t2.company
             AND    t1.addressId = t2.addressId
           )
         ) t2
         INNER JOIN
         (
           SELECT ROWID AS rid,
                  companyNumber,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY companyNumber ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
                  ) AS rn
           FROM   table1
           WHERE  addressId IS NULL
         ) t1
         ON ( t1.companyNumber = t2.company AND t1.rn = t2.rn )
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET addressId = src.addressId;
```

For your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1( refid, CompanyNumber, AddressID ) AS
SELECT 'xyz', 230, CAST(null AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'yzf', 239, null FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2( addressId, company ) AS
SELECT 11223344, 231 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11223345, 230 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11223354, 239 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11223334, 239 FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the merge then for each `NULL` `addressId` in `table1` then a random unmatched `addressId` from `table2` will be set and might (randomly) output:

> | REFID | COMPANYNUMBER | ADDRESSID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | xyz | 230 | 11223345 |
> | yzf | 239 | 11223354 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=020b51fdd8250373c5cc7d0b52b673da)*

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, it worked. I was able to validate the data and it works fine.